# Calling a net.tcp wcf service from Silverlight - in an external facing web site?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, net.tcp

I have an external (public) website developed in Silverlight. The Silverlight app currently calls http based wcf services hosted in IIS.

I am now having to call a wcf service with net.tcp binding hosted in a different app server. I have the net.tcp wcf service hosted in a windows service on port range 4502-4530 and with an interface to expose clientaccesspolicy.xml file as part of the service. I am able to invoke this service from my Silverlight app in the web server. I want the SL app to make direct call to net.tcp, rather than routing the call to it from another http based service.

Question is will this work without any issues when exposed over internet. 
Client browser --> IIS webserver with Silverlight website --> App Server with wcf service on net.tcp.
I am assuming in this case, from XAP SL would try to make direct call to the app server service using net.tcp ?

The communication between the web server and app server could be opened up for ports 4502-4535. But I am wondering what about the client. Does this setup require the ports to be available even in the clients machine (with browser)?

Any insight is much helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2425652; there is sample code included as well! If you setup clientaccesspolicy.xml correctly; it should work as long as clients can access your TCP server.

If your clients are behind some firewall which is blocking your server's ports; they may face connectivity issues!

Comment: Thanks for the link. That helps, infact, I followed the same to host my service and get the infrastructure working in my development environment.  Unfortunately, I am kind of looking for clarity on the real world deployment scenario and especially on the security aspect of doing this for an internet facing deployment.